# Lie algebra of the invertible morphisms of a Lie algebra.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am confused with some facts of Lie groups and Lie algrebras.

1. If a have a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and take its set of invertible morphisms $GL(\mathfrak{g})$ it is clear to me that this is a group. However I don't see why it is a Lie group. What is the differentiable structure on $GL(\mathfrak{g})$?
2. My next confusion is: why can the Lie algebra of $GL(\mathfrak{g})$ be identified with the set of ALL morphisms $\mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: Neither of these statements involve the Lie algebra structure, so here $\mathfrak{g}$ is just a vector space. $GL(\mathfrak{g})$ is just the general linear group $GL_n$ where $n = \dim \mathfrak{g}$. Its Lie algebra is all $n \times n$ matrices as usual.

Comment: I don't know if I am using an incorrect notation but I am thinking: $GL(\mathfrak{g})$ is the set of invertible Lie algebra morphisms.

Comment: That's inconsistent with your second question. It sounds like you're trying to verify something that someone else (a book or a professor) told you, in which case let me tell you right now that in order for your second question to be correct, $GL(\mathfrak{g})$ should refer to the group of all invertible linear maps $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the dimension of ${\cal g}$ is finite. Let $GLin({\cal g})$ be the group of linear maps of ${\cal g}$ it is a Lie group. It is an open subset of $M({\cal g})$ the set of linear endomorphisms of ${\cal g}$. $GL({\cal g})$ is a closed subgroup of $GLin({\cal g})$ thus it is a Lie group.

To determine the Lie algebra of $GL({\cal g})$, you have to find matrices of $M({\cal g})$ whose exponential are in $GL({\cal g})$. If $A$ is such a matrix, by writing the fact that ${d\over{dt}}(exp(tA)[x,y]-[exp(tA)x,exp(tA)y])=0$ you obtain that the Lie algebra of $GL({\cal g})$ is the set of derivations of ${\cal g}$.

Comment: You've misread the question. $GL(\mathfrak{g})$ doesn't denote the group of automorphisms of $\mathfrak{g}$, it denotes the group of all linear maps $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$. (Otherwise the OP's second question doesn't make any sense.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I assume you meant "the group of all _invertible_ linear maps $\frak g\to \frak g$. Otherwise it's not a group.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.